# Can we mix tenses in the same paragraph?

Tags: grammar, tenses, sequence-of-tenses

From an Indian thriller TV show called *Ssshhhh...Koi Hai*

> Ajinkya manages to find his mother but is shocked to know she had never transformed. **He managed** to kill Vikrant but that wouldn’t be the end of him. He enters Vayika’s body, who is injuired in a struggle and in order to finish Vikrant completely, ends up killing Vayika.

In this phrase taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssshhhh...Koi_Hai#Season_3_.282010.29), does the bold part fit correctly with the rest?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Although you have identified a specific part of the quote to ask about, please note that proof-reading questions are explicitly off-topic. Asking the community to proof-read your questions is Not A Good Thing To Do. You may also be interested in [ELL.SE].

Comment: Yes, I have to agree with Andrew Leach's invite. Although this question has its merits, your English doesn't seem to meet the basic requirements of this site. There were a number of grammatical errors in your post which impede comprehension. I think ELL (English Language Learners) is a great place for learners to improve their vocabulary, grammar and general awareness of the English language. Please do consider paying a visit there.

Comment: There are many Wikipedia articles written by non-native English speakers and you should not consider all their sentences grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to say that a sequence {A, B, C} occur in order, you use the same tense. So if the sequence is {shock, kill, enter} then all three should be present tense.

However, if one of the items happened at another time, you can introduce new tenses. So if you want to express this sequence of events;

- Jack loses the ring
- Jane talks to Jack
- Jack tells Jane he has lost it

You could write it like this;

> Jane talks to Jack and asks where the ring is. Jack had lost it, and tells Jane so.

So you get {talks to / had lost / tells}, moving from present, to past perfect, to present.